# Deleting nodes in a database tree

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to simplify or improve how I delete a selected node together with all subnodes below?

Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cats (cat_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                   cat_pid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                   cat_name VARCHAR(40)
                  )
```

The query:

```
WITH tree (cat_id, cat_pid, level, cat_name) AS
(
  SELECT cat_id, cat_pid, 0 as level, cat_name
  FROM cats
  WHERE cat_pid = :cat_id --parameter from FreePascal/Lazarus

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cats.cat_id, cats.cat_pid, tree.level + 1, cats.cat_name
  FROM cats
  INNER JOIN tree ON tree.cat_id = cats.cat_pid
)
DELETE FROM cats
 WHERE cat_id IN (SELECT cat_id FROM tree)
    OR cat_id=:cat_id
```

If possible, I would like to get rid of the OR in the DELETE statement, but dont know how.

Actually, if deletes could be done using foreign keys/cascading deletes it would also be very interesting.

The database is SQLite.

Comment: Looks like SQLite supports `on delete cascade`, if you set up `cat_pid` properly it should "just work": https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions

Comment: I tried, but insert gave a "Foreign KEY constraint failed". cat_pid was set up like this: cat_pid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES cats(cat_id) ON DELETE CASCADE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CTE begins with cats whose *parent* is the specified ID:

```
WHERE cat_pid = :cat_id
```

Just begin what that cat itself:

```
WHERE cat_id = :cat_id
```